# PHP Check if a website use HTTPS

Tags: php, curl, https

Hello I am developing a script and I need some help.

My problem is I want to add a function that will verify if a website use HTTPS or HTTP.

My code...

```
$domain = trim(_GET("domain", "", true));
if(substr($domain, 0, 7) == "http://")
    $domain = substr_replace($domain, "", 0, 7);
$url = "http://" . $domain;
```

I want the `$url` to become `http://` or `https://`, for example when I type `google.com` on my input text, to make it `https://google.com` and not `http://google.com`

Comment: And what exactly is your problem or question? Doesn't this code work? If not, what does/doesn't it do?

Comment: My code is working only for http:// for example if I type google.com (without http:// or www.) is making this string $url = http:// gooogle.com , but the correct link should be $url = https:// google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if port 443 (SSL) is open, see below

```
$domain = trim(_GET("domain", "", true));
if(substr($domain, 0, 7) == "http://")
    $domain = substr_replace($domain, "", 0, 7);

if($fp = fsockopen($domain,443,$errCode,$errStr,1)){   
   $url = "https://" . $domain;
} else {
   $url = "http://" . $domain;
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Sure, should work but I need to implement your code with my code, because I want to check the remote website link, in my case $domain

Comment: replace $host with $domain :) and do your logic in place of comments

Comment: Ok, I have added exactly the code you provided me but now all links become https:// ...

Comment: So they are all supporting SSL

Comment: try 188.132.173.113 port 443 is closed

Comment: I will show you an website for example (clean-up.gr) if you put https:// clean-up.gr is showing an error page and the port is open, but the correct link is http:// clean-up.gr

Comment: Possible typo on the line `if ($fp = fsockopen(*$domaine*`  Shouldn't this be `$domain`

Comment: The code is working, but the problem is this code is searching if the ssl port is open, basically all websites has the https port opened but  the most websites are not working with ssl.